# Which 12.10 desktop version should I use for HP Prolaint N54L?

Tags: installation, 12.10, versions

I recently purchased the HP Proliant N54L microserver to use as a simple fileshare/server at home. I am new to Ubuntu and servers, which is why I'm going to install the desktop rather than the server edition (sadly I need the GUI).

Which version would you recommend? 32-bit or 64-bit? Any other advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should definitely go with 64 bit, as long you are not going to use any specific 32 bit applications (maybe some old games and so).

Cause it is server - you can install something light (like XFCE xubuntu, or LXDE lubuntu). They are pretty light and will still give you access to rest of the apps from repositories.